# C malloc crashing only on second call

Tags: c, crash, malloc, call

I'm having some trouble with a malloc call. The thing is that this call is on a function that I call twice on my program. **The second malloc of the function crashes only on the second time that I call this function**. I tried swapping the order of some of then and even delleting one.. In the first case, the second malloc (originally the first) was crashed, and in the second case, it crashed a realloc that appears later in the same function. Also, I tried calling my function one time before the second and kept crashing on the (new) second call. Can anyone help me? Here is my code:

```
int main(int argv, char *argc[]){
    fsys = malloc(sizeof(struct ext2system)); // Global pointer var

    getsysdata();

    list_dir(fsys->root);
//  list_dir(fsys->root); // IF THIS LINE IS UNCOMMENTED, 
                          // THE PROGRAM CRASHES ON THIS CALL
                          // IF NOT, IT CRASHES ON data = get_cont(fsys->root); 

    pdir dir = malloc(sizeof(struct s_direct));
    int* data;
    int offs, i;


    data = get_cont(fsys->root);  
    offs = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < fsys->root->i_links_count + 2; ++i) {
        offs += readdirent(getblock(data[0])+offs, dir);
        printf("%.*s\n", dir->name_len, dir->name);
        if(dir->file_type==1) printf("%s\n", data);
    }

    unmap(fsys->diskmap);
    return 0;
}

void list_dir(pinode inod){
    // Lists a directory contents
    pdir dir = malloc(sizeof(struct s_direct));
    int* data;
    int offs, i;

    data = get_cont(inod);
    offs = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < inod->i_links_count + 2; ++i) {
        offs += readdirent(getblock(data[0])+offs, dir);
        printf("%.*s\n", dir->name_len, dir->name);
    }

}

int *get_cont(pinode inod){
    // Recupera contenido de los blocks de datos de un inodo
    int *cont=NULL; 
    int *idx=NULL;
    int i=0;
    int *block;

    cont = malloc(sizeof(int));
    idx  = malloc(sizeof(int)); // HERE IS WHERE THE PROGRAM CRASHES
                                // EVEN IF MALLOCS ARE SWAPPED

    while(i < inod->i_blocks && i<13) {
        // Recupera los 12 primeros bloques directamente
            realloc(cont, i*sizeof(int)); // CRASHED HERE WHEN
                                          // I DELETED ONE MALLOC

            cont[i]=inod->i_block[i];
            i++;
    }

    if(i < inod->i_blocks){
        *idx=13;
        block=(int*)getblock(inod->i_block[*idx]);
        fetchcont(block, idx, cont, inod->i_blocks, 0);
    }
    if(i < inod->i_blocks){
        block=(int*)getblock(inod->i_block[*idx]);
        fetchcont(block, idx, cont, inod->i_blocks, 1);
    }
    if(i < inod->i_blocks){
        block=(int*)getblock(inod->i_block[*idx]);
        fetchcont(block, idx, cont, inod->i_blocks, 2);
    }

    return cont;

}
```

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind

Comment: why is idx even allocated and not just an int?

Comment: Using a debugger will help you figure it out. Then you won't need to depend on randoms like us to do your work.

Comment: the first time the `realloc` is called, `i` will be zero, so you'll realloc to 0 bytes.

Comment: @TimothyJones, pdir is defined as follows:
typedef struct s_direct *pdir;
And it is a pointer to s_direct declared on <linux/ext2_fs.h>

Comment: @FrancisUpton is debugging that I figured out where the program crashed. idx is allocated because it is used later on a recursive function and needs to be updated in every execution.

Comment: @TimothyJones if the realloc to 0 bytes is the problem, why doesn't it crashes the first time?

Comment: @Vladimir I've explained more in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is definitely a problem (shortened snippet):

```
int i = 0;

cont = malloc(sizeof(int)); 

while(i < inod->i_blocks && i<13) {

        realloc(cont, i*sizeof(int));
```

The first time through, `i` will be zero at the time of the realloc call. The `malloc()` man page says:

> `realloc()` changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes.  The contents will be unchanged to the minimum of the old and new sizes; newly allocated memory will be uninitialized.  If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to `malloc(size)`, for all values of size; **if size is equal to zero, and ptr is not NULL, then the call
>          is equivalent to `free(ptr)`.**  Unless ptr is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.  If the  area  pointed  to  was  moved, a `free(ptr)` is done.

Since you then go:

```
cont[i]=inod->i_block[i];
```

You'll be writing to memory that you've just freed (Or, when `i` is non-zero, you'll be writing just past the memory you've allocated). This could be anything - you could be overwriting the internal structures of `malloc()`, which could cause a crash later on some invocation of malloc or free.

Also, after the `realloc(cont, 0)`, `cont` will no longer be a pointer returned by `malloc()` (since it's as if you'd written `free(cont);`), and it also won't be null. This will almost certainly crash when `i` is 1.

You probably meant:

```
        realloc(cont, (i+1)*sizeof(int));
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tested it and it worked! 
(This is one of these how-didn't-I-realized-before moments...)

Answer (score 1):

Crashes in the alloc functions mean you've stepped on their bookkeeping data.  Somewhere in the getsysdata() or list_dir() call tree you're assigning through a bad pointer, one that points just exactly far enough past the end of whatever you think it's pointing at to damage malloc's data.  It could have been worse, your overwrites could have stomped on data you care about.